# mypy "Import of 'owclient' ignored"

Tags: python, setuptools, mypy, python-typing, python-poetry

I'm trying to develop a type aware package, following [PEP-561](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/).

- Package repo: https://gitlab.com/fcomabella/ow-client
- A sample project importing the package: https://gitlab.com/fcomabella/test-owclient-types
- The real destination project (a Gtk+ application): https://gitlab.com/fcomabella/pi-homebrew

I want the third project to use type hints. I'm using poetry to manage dependencies in both packages and mypy to check types.

The second project just imports the package. It's intended only as a target to run the mypy command.

But when I run `mypy test-owclient.py --follow-imports=error` in any of the dependant projects, I get the follwing error:

```
test-owclient.py:1: error: Import of 'owclient' ignored
test-owclient.py:1: note: (Using --follow-imports=error, module not passed on command line)
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The mypy command is launched in a virtualenv shell I launch with `poetry shell`.

Initially I used poetry build and poetry publish commands, but got stuck with the issue described here: [poetry issue#1338](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1338)

Then I've tried with setuptools, generated my own setup.py file, based in the one generated by poetry, with the following contents.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# type: ignore
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.rst", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

packages = ['owclient', 'owclient.devices', 'owclient.exc']

package_data = {
    'owclient': ['py.typed'],
    'owclient.devices': ['py.typed'],
    'owclient.exc': ['py.typed'],
    '*': ['pyproject.toml']
}

install_requires = ['pyownet>=0.10.0,<0.11.0']
setup(
    name='owclient',
    version='0.1.8',
    description=(
        'A light layer to use OWFS and pyownet with a more OOP approach.'),
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/x-rst',
    author='Ferran Comabella',
    author_email='ferran@gmail.com',
    maintainer=None,
    maintainer_email=None,
    url='https://gitlab.com/fcomabella/ow-client',
    packages=packages,
    package_data=package_data,
    install_requires=install_requires,
    python_requires='>=3.8,<4.0',
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

But, when I try to run mypy in a project that has the package, I get the same result.

If I run `mypy owclient --follow-imports=error` in the owclient package, I get no errors.

Are those mypy errors expected? What can I do to correct them?

Comment: Can't reproduce with `mypy==0.770`. Cloned both repos, `poetry install` in first, `mypy test-owclient.py` in the second reports `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`. Ran `poetry install --no-root && poetry build` in first, `pip install owclient --find-links=owclient/dist` in second, `mypy test-owclient.py` reports no errors either.

Comment: You're right, the message error show if you use the `--follow-imports=error` option with mypy.

My question is, if the owclient package follows the rules in PEP-561, it has the py.typed files, and the setup.py file is correct, why the `--follow-imports=error` marks it as ignored?

Comment: I've read the mypy documentation, and think this shouldn't happen.